# Get minX, maxX, minY, maxY from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array like this

```
var my_array = [
  [3,9],
  [1,5],
  [7,2],
  [5,4]
 ]
```

As you can see `my_array` is a multidimensional array that includes in this case 4 different arrays.

All of the arrays are x/y-coordinates (`[3,9]` ---> X: 3, Y: 9) and I'd like to move the arrays of the array with ...

- the biggest X value,
- the biggest Y value,
- the smallest X value,
- the smallest Y value

... to an object like this:

```
var my_object = {
  "minX": [1,5],
  "maxX": [7,2],
  "minY": [7,2],
  "maxY": [3,9]
}
```

The function I've created you can find below, but my function is just returning the listed values from above instead of returning the full array. So my current (wrong) result looks like this:

```
var wrong_object = {
  "minX": 1, // missing 5
  "maxX": 7, // missing 2
  "minY": 2, // missing 7
  "maxY": 9  // missing 3
}
```

```js
var my_array = [
  [3, 9],
  [1, 5],
  [7, 2],
  [5, 4]
]

var extreme_result = {}
extreme_result.minX = Math.min.apply(Math, my_array.map(function(i) {
  return i[0]
}));
extreme_result.maxX = Math.max.apply(Math, my_array.map(function(i) {
  return i[0]
}));
extreme_result.minY = Math.min.apply(Math, my_array.map(function(i) {
  return i[1]
}));
extreme_result.maxY = Math.max.apply(Math, my_array.map(function(i) {
  return i[1]
}));

console.log(extreme_result)
```

I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance, Greetings Pete

Comment: I wonder if you could just do two sorts, one on the x and another on the y, and at the end you have your min and maxes from both results at the first and last elements.

Comment: Because there could be more than 4 elements in the `my_array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using es6, you can do something like this:

```js
const my_array = [
  [3,9],
  [1,5],
  [7,2],
  [5,4],
];

const results = {
  xMax: Math.max(...my_array.map(e => e[0])),
  xMin: Math.min(...my_array.map(e => e[0])),
  yMax: Math.max(...my_array.map(e => e[1])),
  yMin: Math.min(...my_array.map(e => e[1]))
}

const points = {
  xMax: my_array.filter(e => e[0] === results.xMax),
  xMin: my_array.filter(e => e[0] === results.xMin),
  yMax: my_array.filter(e => e[1] === results.yMax),
  yMin: my_array.filter(e => e[1] === results.yMin)
}

console.log(points);
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I misread the question. Edit the answer above.

Comment: ?? Thats absolutely not the solution I'd like to get @Brian. I also get this result & thats not the result I'd like to get...

Comment: Hi pete, sorry I misread your question. The answer is above. In case of duplicate minimum values, you should actually have an array of arrays for the minimum/maximum points.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Brian

Comment: Yes, however find only returns the first object found. If there are multiple matches then you will only get the first match.

Answer (score 1):

This sorts the array and grabs the first and last elements for the smallest and largest objects.

```js
var my_array = [
  [3, 9],
  [1, 5],
  [7, 2],
  [5, 4]
];

my_array.sort(function(a, b){ return a[0] - b[0]; });
var minX = my_array[0];
var maxX = my_array[my_array.length - 1];
my_array.sort(function(a, b){ return a[1] - b[1]; });
var minY = my_array[0];
var maxY = my_array[my_array.length - 1];

console.log(JSON.stringify({
  minX: minX,
  maxX: maxX,
  minY: minY,
  maxY: maxY
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function findExtremes( array ){
  let maxX = array[0],
       maxY = array[0],
       minX = array[0],
       minY = array[0];

  for(const [x,y] of array){
    if(x < minX[0]) minX = [x,y];
    if(x > maxX[0]) maxX = [x,y];

    if(y > minY[1]) minY = [x,y];
    if(y < maxY[1]) maxY = [x,y];
  }

  return {maxX, maxY, minX, minY};
}
```

This is O(n) ...

Comment: Set the maxX/Y, minX/Y to the first array element then you can save two comparisons in the loop, do not create new [], use the existing in array for the sake of performance, see my answer.

Comment: @joschi right, ill edit... ( if were giving tips: you should fix your linting, its ugly ;))

Answer (score 0):

I would accomplish this by comparing in a forEach rather than mapping, sorting or whatever.

```js
let my_array = [
  [3, 9],
  [1, 5],
  [7, 2],
  [5, 4]
]

let extreme_result = {
  minX: my_array[0],
  minY: my_array[0],
  maxX: my_array[0],
  maxY: my_array[0]
};

my_array.forEach( (el) => {

  if ( extreme_result.minX[0] > el[0] ) {
    extreme_result.minX = el;
  } else if ( extreme_result.maxX[0] < el[0] ) {
    extreme_result.maxX = el;
  }

  if ( extreme_result.minY[1] > el[1] ) {
    extreme_result.minY = el;
  } else if ( extreme_result.maxY[1] < el[1] ) {
    extreme_result.maxY = el;
  }

});

console.info(extreme_result);
```

Comment: Thanks Joschi. Looks also fine <3

Answer (score 0):

```js
var my_array = [
    [3, 9],
    [1, 5],
    [7, 2],
    [5, 4]
];
let extreme_result={};
extreme_result.MinX=my_array.reduce(function(a,b){
    if(a[0]<b[0]){
        return a;
    }
    else{
        return b;
    }
});
extreme_result.MinY=my_array.reduce(function(a,b){
    if(a[1]<b[1]){
        return a;
    }
    else{
        return b;
    }
});
extreme_result.MaxX=my_array.reduce(function(a,b){
    if(a[0]>b[0]){
        return a;
    }
    else{
        return b;
    }
});
extreme_result.MaxY=my_array.reduce(function(a,b){
    if(a[1]>b[1]){
        return a;
    }
    else{
        return b;
    }
});
console.log(extreme_result);
```